# Module version in composer.json

Tags: magento2.2, composer, magento2.3, semantic-versioning

I'm running the static tests on one of my modules and on magento version 2.3 it reports an inconsistency:

> Version must not be specified in the root and package composer JSON files in Git
>   Failed asserting that object of class "stdClass" does not have attribute "version".

This does not happen for magento 2.2.
After some digging around I found that there is this test `Magento\Test\Integrity\ComposerTest::assertNoVersionSpecified()`

```
/**
 * Version must not be specified in the root and package composer JSON files in Git.
 *
 * All versions are added by tools during release publication by version setter tool.
 *
 * @param \StdClass $json
 */
private function assertNoVersionSpecified(\StdClass $json)
{
    $errorMessage = 'Version must not be specified in the root and package composer JSON files in Git';
    $this->assertObjectNotHasAttribute('version', $json, $errorMessage);
}
```

On the other hand, the official docs state that the version should be specified in `composer.json`: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/versioning/

I need a confirmation that the `composer.json` should not contain the module version anymore.
In case the answer is `Yes` for the question above, I could use an explanation on how does magento know the version of the modules installed via composer if the version is missing from `composer.json`.

Comment: In newer versions they are dropping version number from composer.json without proper documentation https://github.com/magento-engcom/import-export-improvements/commit/95bfd2c790f9f84c81f0f25807623d136555f7ea